# Perl STDERR redirect failing

Tags: perl, file-handling, stderr

A common functions script that our systems use uses a simple STDERR redirect in order to create user-specific error logs. it goes like this

```
# re-route standard out to text file
close STDERR;
open STDERR, '>>', 'd:/output/Logs/STDERR_' . &parseUsername($ENV{REMOTE_USER}) . '.txt'
   or die "couldn't redirect STDERR: $!";
```

Now, I copy-pasted this to my own functions script for a system-specific error log, and while it'll compile, it breaks the scripts that require it. Oddly enough, it doesn't even print the error that the children script are throwing. My *slightly* modified version looks like,

```
close STDERR;
open (STDERR, '>>', 'err/STDERR_SPORK.txt')
  or die print "couldn't redirect STDERR: $!";
```

everything compiles fine in command prompt, `-c` returns ok, and if I throw a warn into the function script, and compile, it outputs properly. I still do not understand why though this kills the children. I cut out the redirect, and sure enough they work. Any thoughts?

Comment: `or die print ...`????

Comment: @ikegami I was having an issue where it was failing on the open, and it wouldn't say why. Adding print at least let me know why open was failing. The cause has since been fixed.

Answer (score 4):

`die` (and `warn`) writes to `STDERR`. If you close `STDERR` and then need to `die` as you attempt to reopen it, where would you expect to see the error message?

Since this is Perl, there are many ways to address this issue. Here are a couple.

1. open the file first to a tmp filehandle, reassign it to STDERR if everything goes ok

   ```
   if (open my $tmp_fh, '>>', 
      'd:/output/Logs/STDERR_' . &parseUsername($ENV{REMOTE_USER}) . '.txt') {
      close STDERR;
      *STDERR = *$tmp_fh;
   } else {
      die "couldn't redirect STDERR: $!";
   }
   ```
2. Use `con`. For programs that you run from a command line, most systems have a concept of "the current terminal". In Unix systems, it's `/dev/tty` and on Windows, it's `con`. Open an output stream to this terminal pseudo-file.

   ```
   open STDERR, '>>', 
      'd:/output/Logs/STDERR_' . &parseUsername($ENV{REMOTE_USER}) . '.txt'
      or do {
          open my $tty_fh, '>', 'con';
          print $tty_fh "couldn't redirect STDERR: $!";
          exit 1;
      };
   ```

Comment: Writing to `CON:` or `/dev/tty` in a CGI script isn't useful.

Comment: @ikegami in their defense, I did mention using the command line, but you're right. This is a CGI script, therefore command line redirects won't be too helpfull

Comment: In the first snippet, STDERR ends up not being fd 2. That can cause issues. I think you can solve that by replacing `close STDERR;
           *STDERR = *$tmp_fh;
` with `open STDERR, '<&', $tmp_fh or die $!;`

Answer (score 0):

After changing nothing in the script, and poking around in the server, and changing nothing, it now works as expected. I don't know what to say to be honest.

Comment: Follow up on it -- now it sounds interesting.  And something you may _want to_ know.